# C# Pinvoke - How can I know what's wrong with my managed definitions?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I need to wrap an unmanaged function with pinvoke in my C# program.
Is there any way I can know whether or not my managed declaration in C# matches the native one?
I noticed that if it doesn't match, when I try to call it no execption is thrown so I can't know if the function was really called.
(The unmanaged function is from a 3rd party component so I can't put in it logs or change it.)

Comment: AFAIK you can't be sure about signature of an unmanaged imported function. If they don't match probably you'll produce garbage (or access violations). You don't have anything like that even when you do everything on native side (imagine to change - let's say - definition of fopen(), it'll compile but it'll crash).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to automatically check that your p/invoke declaration matches the native function. The onus is on you to get it right.

Often if you get it wrong an exception will be raised. But not always.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally I have replicated a complex function signature in my own unmanaged DLL and tested that to learn exactly how arguments are marshaled by P/Invoke. You can then debug from the managed code into the unmanaged code if you enable unmanaged debugging in your managed project and this can assist you in troubleshooting why P/Invoke fails.